# How to use IF THAN statements on date but converting it to time

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

On `B2`, I'm trying to put in an IF timevalue statement on a datetimevalue statement with this formula

```
=IF (A2 < TIME (7,30,0), "PREM", IF (A2 >= TIME (7,30,0), "INTRA", "0"))
```

However it doesn't come out as I planned. It kept showing all of column `B` to be INTRA instead. How can I convert it so that it looks like the graph below?

```
+------------------+-------------+
|    TIME IN       | INTRA/PREM  |
+------------------+-------------+
| 2/5/2020 7:09:37 | PREM        |
| 2/5/2020 8:01:05 | INTRA       |
+------------------+-------------+
```

I don't know if I explained it correctly, but I want column `B` to calculate the datetimevalue of column `A` to either be "PREM" if the time is before 7:30AM, or "INTRA" if the time is at 7:30AM or after 7:30AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the  `IFS` and `TIMEVALUE` functions as well

```
=IFS (TIMEVALUE(A2) >= TIME (7,30,0), "INTRA",TIMEVALUE(A2) < TIME (7,30,0), "PREM")
```

You could even use an Arrayformula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFS (TIMEVALUE(A2:A3) >= TIME (7,30,0), "INTRA",TIMEVALUE(A2:A3) < TIME (7,30,0), "PREM"))
```